# Data from database not display correct in html table in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, html-table

I have problem with displaying data because know everything shows in one column and 300 rows...
I want to my table generate dynamically column (form param in url) and rows (result form data base).

For now it looks like this (not everything is in the picture because it does not fit):
[image]

And data form API looks like this:

> [{"nazwa_art":"11_15_0351","nazwa_rys":"11_002258_A0","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K",
>   "py_1":"x","py_2":"x","py_3":"x","py_4":"x","py_5":"x","py_6":"x","py_7":"K","py_8":"K","py_9":"x","py_10":"x","py_11":"x"},{"nazwa_art":"11_15_0200","nazwa_rys":"11_002258_A0","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K,PBlue5575,PGreenYellow5576","py_1":"x","py_2":"PGreenYellow5576","py_3":"PGreenYellow5576",
>   "py_4":"PBlue5575","py_5":"PBlue5575","py_6":"x","py_7":"x","py_8":"x","py_9":"x","py_10":"x","py_11":"x"},{"nazwa_art":"11_15_0492","nazwa_rys":"11_002258_A0","kolory_art":"C,M,Y,K,PBlue5575,PGreenYellow5576","py_1":"x","py_2":"PGreenYellow5576","py_3":"PGreenYellow5576",
>   "py_4":"PBlue5575","py_5":"PBlue5575","py_6":"PGreenYellow5576","py_7":"PGreenYellow5576","py_8":"x","py_9":"x","py_10":"x","py_11":"x"}]

My code:
controller.js

```
'use strict';

var pokayokaCtr = angular.module( 'pokayokaCtr' , [ 'ngRoute' ] );

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawings' , [ '$scope' , '$http', function( $scope, $http ){


    $http.get( 'api/admin/drawings/get' ).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.drawings = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Błąd pobrania pliku z bazy danych! Drawings' );
    });

}]);

pokayokaCtr.controller( 'drawingCreate' , [ '$scope' , '$http' , '$timeout', function( $scope , $http, $timeout){

    $scope.createDrawing = function ( drawing ) {


        $http.post('api/admin/drawings/create', {
            drawing : drawing
        }).success(function(){

            $timeout(function(){
                $scope.success = false;

                $scope.drawing = {};
            } , 1500 );
            console.log($scope.drawing);

        }).error(function(){
            console.log('Error database connect!')
        });

    };

}]);


pokayokaCtr.controller( 'pokayokes' , [ '$scope' , '$http', '$routeParams', '$timeout', function( $scope, $http, $routeParams, numberColFilter, $timeout ){

    var pokayokeName = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.name = pokayokeName;

    var number = $routeParams.number;
    $scope.number = number; 

    $http.get( 'api/admin/pokayokes/get/' + pokayokeName + '/'+ number).
    success( function( data ){
        $scope.pokayokes = data;
    }).error( function(){
        console.log( 'Error database connect!' );
    });





}]);

pokayokaCtr.filter('numberColFilter', function() {
     return function(items, number) {

        var range = [];

        var start = 7;
        var end = parseInt(start) + parseInt(number);
        console.log(end);

        for (var i = start; i < end; i++)
        {
            range.push(items[i]);
        }

        console.log(range);
        return range;
  };
});
```

and view (only row with table):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="flat-panel">
            <div class="flat-panel-header">
                        <h2 class="pull-left">Artykuły w rysunku</h2>
                        <a ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes | limitTo: 1  track by $index" class="pull-right btn btn-primary"  href="#/admin/article/create/part1/{{ pokayoke.nazwa_rys}}" style="margin: 20px 0 15px;"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Dodaj nowy artykuł</a>                             
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="flat-panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Lp.</th>
                                <th>Obrazek</th>
                                <th>Nazwa artykułu <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> </th>
                                <th >Kolory w artykule</th>
                                <th ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes  track by $index">{{$index + 1 }}</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="pokayoke in pokayokes track by $index" >
                                <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
                                <td><a href=""> <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Zobacz</a></td>
                                <td>{{pokayoke.nazwa_art}}</i> </td>
                                <td>{{pokayoke.kolory_art}}</td>
                                <td ng-repeat="num in pokayoke " >{{ num }}</td>   

                            </tr>                               
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> <!-- /responive -->
            </div>
        </div><!-- /flat-panel -->
    </div>
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

and looks url with params:

> http://somename.com/testy/py/api/admin/pokayokes/get/11_002258_A0/11

Where could be error or something wrong written?

Comment: logic doesn't make sense in `ng-repeat` . You are making as many columns (+5)  as there are data rows

Comment: So how should be looks like ng-repeat? I need to the columns will be generated dynamic, I also have write filter, but it not working...